# How do I calculate arc angle between two points on a circle?

Tags: math

Given a circle with a known center point and two points on the circle (thus known radius), how do I determine the angle of the minimum arc between the two points on the circle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn the center to the two points into a pair of vectors, then shove through [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_%28geometry%29#Dot_product).

So, cos<sup>-1</sup> ((x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + y<sub>1</sub>y<sub>2</sub> + z<sub>1</sub>z<sub>2</sub>) / r<sup>2</sup>).