# Unknown value in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, math

While doing some calculations in Visual Studio C++ I found the final value of `angle` to be `-1.#IND000000000000`

What does this value mean? Has it gone out of scope?
Following is the code I was trying to implement *How do I calculate arc angle between two points on a circle?* from this formula 
 cos<sup>-1</sup> ((x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + y<sub>1</sub>y<sub>2</sub> + z<sub>1</sub>z<sub>2</sub>) / r<sup>2</sup>) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2994683/603125)

**CODE**

```
double x = vec1X * vec2X;
double y = vec1Y * vec2Y;
double r = sqrt(((vec2X - originX) * (vec2X - originX))+((vec2Y - originY) * (vec2Y - originY)));
angle = acos ((x + y) / r*r);
```

Sample values to reproduce error

```
vec1X = 91.094001770019531;
vec1Y = 147.74990844726562;
vec2X = 94.163322448730469;
vec2Y = 187.93711853027344;
originX = 136.79920959472656;
originY = 223.69624328613281;
```

Comment: Link to explanation of that particular NaN

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means the result is indeterminate; a more standard term is "not a number" or "NaN".

Possible reasons here are:

- the argument to `sqrt` is negative
- both operands of the division are zero
- the argument to `acos` is outside the range `[-1,1]`.

Any of these can happen due to floating-point rounding errors, even if mathematically they should not be possible; so you should always check values before passing them to functions with a limited input range.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `acos` argument should lie in [-1.0 .. 1.0], and your is not. For example if `r` is close to zero, you have big error. If you are sure , that input is ok, than, try to map values smaller than -1 to -1, and greater 1 to 1

Answer (score 1):

It's a [NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean) value.

It actually means an "indeterminate" value, which means it could be "anything". Dividing 0 by 0 is an "indeterminate".

without calculating these, what is the value of the argument in acos? (It should be between -1 and 1)